# Old ASP.NET code works on one computer, not on another?

Tags: asp.net, reference, global-asax

So in my global.asax, I've got the following code:

```
Inventory.BusinessTier bt = new Inventory.BusinessTier();
string UserLogin = bt.ExtractLogin (Request.ServerVariables ["AUTH_USER"]);
Inventory.User myUser = new Inventory.User (UserLogin);
Session ["User"] = myUser;
```

It works just fine on one development PC, but using the same version of Visual Studio, it craps out on the third line with this error:

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
> 'Inventory.DataTier' threw an exception.'
> Inner Exception
> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
> object.

Other than a line adding impersonation in my web.config (it has to be there now), I haven't changed a single thing.  Is there a way to get more info on this?  I can't even trace it, because if I put a debug line in the User object constructor, it never hits it.  I'm at a bit of a loss.  Would appreciate any advice.

EDIT to answer questions below:

InventoryUser is a very simple user object that reads the current from the database and stores some basic user info in properties, such as UserID, Role, RoleID, and IsAdmin.

The DataTier class is a class that interacts with the database.  It is used in multiple projects, so I'm quite sure it's not the problem.  I tried to paste in the code anyway, but it exceeded the limit for a post.

I'm reasonably sure the problem is related to the user class.  It's short, so I can paste it in here:

```
using System;
using System.Data;

// This is the user business object.  It contains information pertaining to the current user of the application.  Notably, it
// contains the department ID, which determines what inventory items the user will see when using the application.  Only
// specified employees with admin access can see all items for all departments, and that is determined by a specific department ID.

namespace Inventory {

    public class User {

        private Guid _UserID;
        private Guid _RoleID;
        private Guid _UserDepartmentID;
        private string _UserRole        = "";
        private string _UserName        = "";
        private bool _IsAuthorizedUser  = false;
        private bool _IsAdmin           = false;

        // Attribute declarations
        public Guid UserID {
            get {
                return _UserID;
            }
            set {
                _UserID = value;
            }
        }
        public string UserRole {
            get {
                return _UserRole;
            }
            set {
                _UserRole = value;
            }
        }
        public Guid RoleID {
            get {
                return _RoleID;
            }
            set {
                _RoleID = value;
            }
        }
        public string UserName {
            get {
                return _UserName;
            }
            set {
                _UserName = value;
            }
        }
        public Guid UserDepartmentID {
            get {
                return _UserDepartmentID;
            }
            set {
                _UserDepartmentID = value;
            }
        }
        public bool IsAdmin {
            get {
                return _IsAdmin;
            }
            set {
                _IsAdmin = value;
            }
        }
        public bool IsAuthorizedUser {
            get {
                return _IsAuthorizedUser;
            }
            set {
                _IsAuthorizedUser = value;
            }
        }


        // -----------------
        // -  Constructor  -
        // -----------------
        public User (string UserLogin) {
            
            string ShortUserLogin = ExtractLogin (UserLogin);
            GetUser (ShortUserLogin);
        }

        
        // ------------------
        // -  ExtractLogin  -
        // ------------------
        public string ExtractLogin (string Login) {

            // The domain and "\" symbol must be removed from the string, leaving only the user name.

            int pos = Login.IndexOf (@"\");
            return Login.Substring (pos + 1, Login.Length - pos - 1);
        }


        // -------------
        // -  GetUser  -
        // -------------
        // This method is called to fill the user object based on the user's login.  It ultimately gets authorized user data
        // from the user table.
        public void GetUser (string UserName) {

            DataTier dt1 = new DataTier();
            DataTable dt = dt1.GetUserInfo (UserName);
            int RecordCount = dt.Rows.Count;

            switch (RecordCount) {

                case 1:                 // There is one user name match, as there should be.  This is the likely situation.
                    DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];
                    UserID              = (Guid)dr ["UserID"];
                    UserRole            = (string)dr ["UserRole"];
                    RoleID              = (Guid)dr ["RoleID"];
                    this.UserName       = UserName;
                    UserDepartmentID    = (Guid)dr ["DepartmentID"];
                    IsAdmin             = (bool)dr ["IsAdmin"];
                    IsAuthorizedUser    = true;
                    break;

                case 0:                 // There are no user name matches (unauthorized use).
                    IsAdmin = false;
                    IsAuthorizedUser = false;
                    break;

                default:                // There are multiple user name matches (problem!).
                    IsAdmin = false;
                    IsAuthorizedUser = false;
                    break;
            }


        }


    }
}
```

Comment: As a starting point, compare Request.ServerVariables ["AUTH_USER"] between 2 environments. Afterwards compare UserLogin. Are they the same?

Comment: Yes sir, they are correct in both environments.

Comment: What is Inventory.User?

Comment: Please share the Inventory class code (including the datatier and user)

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.  I have added the User class to my original post.  The DataTier was too large to paste in, but it has been tested and used in multiple projects so I know it is not a problem.

Comment: UPDATE:  I just realized I was compiling release mode, not debug.  I changed it back to debug, and it seems to be working!  I have no idea why.